# Windows 10 cannot access Samba Share but can from other devices

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-10, network-shares, samba

I know there are tons of these questions out there, but I've read all the ones with even remotely similar titles and a few blogs to go with it, and I can't wrap my head around why it's still a problem. I have a Samba server on an Ubuntu machine. It has two shares, the one I'm interested in is simply called "share". From my phone and either of my two chromebooks, I can access both shares with read/write privileges, but my Windows 10 laptop can't access either share. It just spits out this super helpful error:

[image: Network Error]

Transfering each file through winSCP to view/edit it is going to be a massive pain in the area I'm about to shove this server, so I'd appreciate any thoughts on the issue.

I have homegroups enabled but can give them up if it'll fix this problem, so far it hasn't.

I do not have local security policies, even directly running *secpol.msc* returns a "Cannot Find" error.

Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in the Network Adapter properties. I needed to enable the Client for Microsoft Networks *thing*, which I hadn't done as shown here:

[image: Network Adapter Properties]

Once I enabled that and rebooted, the network file share was accessible.

Comment: Where are these *"Network Adapter properties"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Open the Network and Sharing Center (Windows 7 and Up, it might work in Vista too) from Control Panel. Click "Change adapter settings" in the left pane. Right-click on the adapter, and select "Properties".